# PHP Limit rows returned by MySQL and do something if last row returned

Tags: php, mysql

I didn't know exactly how to word this question but by do something I mean that I would like to hide or not show my "next" button that is shown below. I have a script that pulls all the images from MySQL and prints them to my page by 30 images per page and the next 30 will create a new page that is activated by my back/next buttons. My "back" button has a if statement if $startrow isn't >= 0 than it won't show but I would like the same concept with my next button when the last row in my database is shown and it hides my next button.

I was thinking if you can detect the first empty row or the last row of the database and if so hide the next button. Otherwise it keeps adding 30 to $startrow when nothing is shown on screen.

I found a script helping me with this [here](http://www.phpsimplicity.com/tips.php?id=1) but it didn't tell me how to hide the next button.

```
<?php
$startrow = $_GET['startrow'];

if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
  $startrow = 0;  
} else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}
?>
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "media");
$uploaded = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images LIMIT $startrow, 30");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($uploaded)) {
    echo "<div class='img_container'>";
    echo "<li><img class='img_box' src='uploads/images/".$row['image_title']."' ></li>";
    echo "</div>";
}

$prev = $startrow - 30;
if ($prev >= 0) {
    echo '<div class="prevRow"><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$page.'&startrow='.$prev.'">Back</a></div>';
}
    echo '<div class="nextRow"><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$page.'&startrow='.($startrow+30).'">Next</a></div>';
?>
```

Comment: How large is the dataset?

Comment: Usually when you are paginating you have counted how many row there are in total so you know when to do things like this. Does your code do a count of all the possible results rows?

Comment: Currently it's 26 but that's not a static number because I uploaded those images and plan to upload more

Comment: So you need to start the process by counting all the possible rows

Comment: Could I just use a mysqli_num_rows function and return the amount of rows or something

Comment: No because your current query is always limited to 30 ( or something ).

Comment: It prints 30 results at a time and adds the next 30 results when the next button is clicked

Comment: I just added if ( mysqli_num_rows( $uploaded ) { echo '<div class="nextRow"><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$page.'&startrow='.($startrow+30).'">Next</a></div>'; } and it actually worked except it lets me click next to a blank page before it didn't show any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like

```
$num_rows = 30;  // rows on a page

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "media");

// get total possible rows
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT count(id) FROM images");
$row = $res->fetch_row();
$total_rows = $row[0];
$res->close();


$uploaded = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images LIMIT $startrow, $num_rows");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($uploaded)) {  
    . . .
}


$prev = $startrow - $num_rows;
if ($prev >= 0) {
    echo '<div class="prevRow"><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$page.'&startrow='.$prev.'">Back</a></div>';
}

if ( $startrow+$num_rows < $total_rows  ) {
    echo '<div class="nextRow"><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$page.'&startrow='.($startrow+30).'">Next</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: Okay at first I attempted using your code and for some reason it wasn't working so I changed it a little bit but went back to yours and now it works so I don't know what that was about but now it's working like I wanted so thank you

Answer (score 0):

Potentially a little faster than the answer from @RiggsFolly, you can modify your existing query to count the rows.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND ROWS * FROM images LIMIT $startrow, 30
```

Then, after the query returns, you run a second query to get the answer:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

The [`FOUND_ROWS()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) returns the number of rows the previous query would have returned, without `LIMIT` (or an offset).

This is probably not as fast as your original query would be in isolation, but should be slightly faster than `SELECT COUNT(...) ...` followed by your original query.  With small data sets, though, any differences will likely be below measurable limits.

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html

You can also combine these things into a stored procedure that accepts items per page and page number, and returns all of the records along with metadata items such as the total number of pages.